# What does the MDN web worker "About thread safety" example want to tell us?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I want to use web worker in my code, and to avoid subtle problems, I read this [section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#About_thread_safety) of MDN. 
MDN states the code below is "of a catastrophy", so I guess the codes will cause some strange behaviors impalpablely.

The codes intends to create a canvas, whose content comes from a web worker. The web worker generates the image data in 60FPS and post a message contains the image data to main.js. But MDN doesn't explain what exactly problem will occur, so I have to guess.

1. The screen can't be refreshed in 60FPS, say if 50FPS, because of the `context.putImageData(imageData);` takes a little longer time if drawing a retina screen, the posted message from web worker cannot get a in time response, so the posted message will be accumulated to cause the main screen locking or no response?
2. If the "Data passed between the main page and workers is copied, not shared.", would the situation in 1 means serious memory leak?
3. ... Needs your help to point problems.

Vise versa, if the code is written as main.js calls the data from web worker, for example postMessage to web worker to query, but in very high frequency, and the algorithm in web worker would take relatively long time, cannot response in time to main.js, what would happen?

Or my understanding is wrong, the problems the codes want to demonstrate are totally different.

Needs your help. Thanks in advance.

*HTML Content*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multithreading Catastrophy</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0px; }
        canvas { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right:0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>
    <script src="main.js" async></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

*main.js Content*

```
// main.js
var myworker = new Worker("worker.js"), width=window.innerWidth, height=window.innerHeight, context=document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var imagedatatmp=context.createImageData(width,height);

myworker.onmessage = function(data){
    imageData = imagedatatmp.from(data);
};

setTimeout(function draw_canvas() {
    context.putImageData(imageData);
    setTimeout(draw_canvas, 1000/60);
},10);

window.onresize = window.reload; // Quick (to type) n' dirty way to resize;
```

*worker.js Content*

```
// worker.js
window.onmessage = function(width, height){
var noise = function(x, y, z) {
    var p = new Array(512), permutation = [151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180];
    for (var i = 0;i < 256;i++) p[256 + i] = p[i] = permutation[i];
    var X = Math.floor(x) & 255, Y = Math.floor(y) & 255, Z = Math.floor(z) & 255; x -= Math.floor(x), y -= Math.floor(y), z -= Math.floor(z);
    var u = fade(x), v = fade(y), w = fade(z);
    var A = p[X] + Y, AA = p[A] + Z, AB = p[A + 1] + Z, B = p[X + 1] + Y, BA = p[B] + Z, BB = p[B + 1] + Z;
    return scale(lerp(w, lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA], x, y, z), grad(p[BA], x - 1, y, z)), lerp(u, grad(p[AB], x, y - 1, z), grad(p[BB], x - 1, y - 1, z))), lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA + 1], x, y, z - 1), grad(p[BA + 1], x - 1, y, z - 1)), lerp(u, grad(p[AB + 1], x, y - 1, z - 1), grad(p[BB + 1], x - 1, y - 1, z - 1)))));
};
  function fade(t) { return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10); }
  function lerp(t, a, b) { return a + t * (b - a); }
  function grad(hash, x, y, z) {
    var h = hash & 15; var u = h < 8 ? x : y, v = h < 4 ? y : h == 12 || h == 14 ? x : z;
    return ((h & 1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h & 2) == 0 ? v : -v);
  }
  function scale(n) { return (1 + n) / 2; }
var length = width*height; var canvasnoisedata=new UInt32Array(length);

setTimeout(function make_noise() {
var i=length, z=Math.random()*1024;
  while ( i-- ) {
      canvasnoisedata[i] = noise(i%width+z,i/width+z,z);
  }
  setTimeout(make_noise, 1000/60);
},1000/60);

setTimeout(function post_noise() {
    postMessage( canvasnoisedata );
    setTimeout(post_noise, 1000/60);
},1000/60);
};
```

Comment: the only `catastrophe` I can see in that code is 1. window is undefined in a worker, 2. imageData is undefined, 3. putIMageData requires 3 or 7 arguments, not just 1

Comment: @Jaromanda X, can't be such grammar mistakes. windows is the context. imageData is a global variable, putIMageData 's arguments can be omitted...

Comment: I'm just telling you what firefox is complaining about :p and workers **do not have window** as the global scope, the global scope in a worker is [DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope) - yes, `imageData` is global, sloppy code example ... and firefox compalins about `context.putImageData(imageData)` with the message *Not enough arguments to CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData*

Comment: @Jaromanda X, what about thread safety? If the codes are in the content of "About thread Safety"...

Comment: seeing as the code doesn't run ... I'd say it's thread safe :p - seriously though, not sure what MDN is trying to say with that code

Comment: There are many errors in the example, but I guess they try to show how to overload both main and worker processes, as well as the message-port pipe with large data blocks that are copied not transferred, as it pushes several messages to/from worker every 1/60 frame using (nested) setTimeouts to calculate the simplex-noise data, instead of simply using the message mechanism once (main.post - worker.handle - worker.postResult - main.use, repeat) per frame (this will also cause the calls to be out of order).

Comment: @Jaromanda X, thanks all the same!

Comment: @K3N, "this will also cause the calls to be out of order", how does out of order happen? Because the heavy load blocks something?